# Inkscape - easy way to make a lace design?

Tags: inkscape

Was playing around with designing clothes on Inkscape, and was wondering if you are able to make lace? I've already tried to make lace with the Bezier Curve, but every time I try it looks awful. Any easier ways?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Imbrosia! Can you tell us something about your efforts or be more specific on your question? e.g. what's really *awful*? Have you explored [this old thread](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=11511)?

Answer (score 2):

There's an extension for making a pattern for an actual lace (not only a drawing of one), maybe it could be useful to you: https://tesselace.com/2017/10/31/inkscape-for-bobbin-lace/

If it's circular, the 'rotate copies' live path effect is an option, too.

Comment: Thank you for this, I shall check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you may want to use two features inherent in Inkscape.

The first is [tiled clones](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/repeating-patterns-made-easy-in-inkscape--cms-20284), which allows you to create an array of any object, path or group. There's quite a bit of flexibility within the settings for that feature.

The second feature is [interpolate](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/interpolate/tutorial-interpolate.html). Interpolation in this context requires a "start" object and an "end" object and generates a fill-in array which adjusts the item/object in a morphing sort of way.

You need only to create a small section of your desired lace and use those two features to create a pattern. The level of adjustment available with both of them is quite spectacular.

I recognize that link-only answers are not a good idea, but the features are complex enough that it's difficult to provide a useful summary/instruction for them. Alternatively, user searches for the terms will provide more options.